# What does exactly *.* mean when used in IMAP command?

Tags: imap, rfc

I know that using * in IMAP FETCH Command either defines all or one mail but does 
"*:*" also defines all mails in the selected folder? Does it defines something else too? Asking cause my company is implementing its own IMAP server, and I couldn't find any reference to *:* in the RFC 3501 and 4466.

If possible, please also cite the RFC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` does not mean all mail. As a number, `*` means "the last message in the folder". More generally, `42` means "message 42", `42:50` means "messages 42 to 50 inclusive", `42:*` "messages 42 to the last one", and `*` means "the last message", see? `*:*` is another way to say "just the last message".

But *.* doesn't mean anything in particular. I can't think of any case where that is even syntactically valid.

Comment: My bad. I had meant "*:*" and not "*.*" . My apologies. Corrected the question. But can you please cite an RFC? We just want to be sure we are coding right.

Comment: RFC 3501, page 90, the definition of sequence-set (and the others on that page). The entire section 9 is worth reading very carefully.

Answer (score 0):

*:* would mean just the last message. You can check for rfc 791. Check www.tools.ietf.org